# How to compare strings from the first row to every other row in a data frame and count the number of mismatches in R?

Tags: r, compare, rows

I have a data frame with thousands of rows and columns where I need to count the changes of character variables from the first row to every other row (row1–row2, row1–row3, row1–row4, …) and output the total number of changes into a new column.

```
df <- data_frame(
  a = c("1 2", "1 2", "2 2", "2 2"),
  b = c("2 1", "1 2", "1 2","1 2"),
  c = c("1 1", "1 2", "2 1","2 2"),
  d = c("1 1", "1 1", "2 1","2 1")
)

df
a     b     c     d    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1 2   2 1   1 1   1 1  
2 1 2   1 2   1 2   1 1  
3 2 2   1 2   2 1   2 1  
4 2 2   1 2   2 2   2 1
```

I want to count the character mismatches between each element from row 1 to row 2, row 1 to row 3 and so on. So that I get this:

```
   a     b     c     d   e   
1 1 2   2 1   1 1   1 1  NA #No mismatches to count since this is the first row. 
2 1 2   1 2   1 2   1 1  3 
3 2 2   1 2   2 1   2 1  5
4 2 2   1 2   2 2   2 1  6
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` approach could be:

```
bind_cols(df, df %>%
           mutate_all(~ strsplit(., " ", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
           mutate_all(~ map2_int(.x = ., .y = .[1], ~ sum(.x != .y))) %>%
           transmute(e = rowSums(select(., everything()))))

  a     b     c     d         e
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 1 2   2 1   1 1   1 1       0
2 1 2   1 2   1 2   1 1       3
3 2 2   1 2   2 1   2 1       5
4 2 2   1 2   2 2   2 1       6
```

Or using only `dplyr`:

```
bind_cols(df, df %>%
           mutate_all(~ rowSums(drop(attr(adist(., first(.), count = TRUE), "counts")))) %>%
           transmute(e = rowSums(select(., everything()))))
```

Comment: Might be worth adding a little text explaining that the key operation here is to go row-by-row and take the `sum ( df[1,] != df[j,]) ` .

Comment: Thank you very much, I have already tried it in the whole data and it works!

Answer (score 2):

You can use base R matrices with the `stringdist` package for a simple, somewhat more flexible solution (i.e. if your data contain more complicated strings):

```r
library(stringdist)

m <- t(df)
df$e <- colSums(matrix(stringdist(m[,1], m), ncol(df)))
```

**Output**:

```
  a     b     c     d         e
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 1 2   2 1   1 1   1 1       0
2 1 2   1 2   1 2   1 1       3
3 2 2   1 2   2 1   2 1       5
4 2 2   1 2   2 2   2 1       6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also tried it and it also works as I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(e = pmap(., ~toString(c(...)) %>% charToRaw),
         e = map_dbl(e, ~ sum(.x != e[[1]])))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  a     b     c     d         e
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 1 2   2 1   1 1   1 1       0
2 1 2   1 2   1 2   1 1       3
3 2 2   1 2   2 1   2 1       5
4 2 2   1 2   2 2   2 1       6
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! I tried it and it also works fine.